# WiX Error LGHT0204: ICE03: _Validation table: Data in KeyTAble column is incorrect;

Tags: wix

I am getting this error in my Wix project, and I am not able to get a clear solution in the web for this error:

```
error LGHT0204: ICE03: _Validation table: Data in KeyTAble column is incorrect; Table: MsiAssembly, Column: Feature_, Key(s): Component_USBComm_x86
```

and also this error:

```
error LGHT0204: ICE57: Component 'Component_HTMLHelp' has both per-user and per-machine data with a per-machine KeyPath.
```

Any idea or pointers to understanding what I might be doing wrong?

Answer (score 4):

The first error tells me that you have a problem in your _Validation table.  The second one tells me you have a component that mixes per machine and per user resources in a single component.  I am wondering from the component names if you authored this in WiX or if you are picking up a third party merge module that is introducing the problem into the built MSI.

**ICE03** [link text](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa368798(VS.85).aspx)
_Validation table: Data in KeyTable column is incorrect The KeyTable column in the _Validation table references a table that does not exist in the database.

**ICE57** [link text](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa368994(VS.85).aspx)
ICE57 validates that individual components do not mix per-machine and per-user data. This ICE custom action checks registry entries, files, directory key paths, and non-advertised shortcuts.

Mixing per-user and per-machine data in the same component could result in only partial installation of the component for some users in a multi-user environment.

Comment: Thanks for your response..I am new to the WiX setup. All the component names are authored in the wix project itself. How can I look up the keytable column? Where is the _Validation table stored?

Comment: You can edit the built MSI with ORCA ( MSI database editor ) perform validation and see the effected tables and rows.  I'd have to look at your wxs file to see what is wrong.

Comment: Thanks for the pointer to ORCA. That gave me some idea as to what is going wrong. Basically my entire <feature> table is missing in the msi. I had grouped all the features as a fragment in a separate fragment.wxs. Do I need to do any backlink in that fragment to indicate that the features belong to the product?

Comment: Take a look at the FeatureGroup, FeatureGroupRef and FeatureRef elements